# Greendao: how insert "blob"

Tags: android, orm, greendao

GreenDao. How insert image file (png) for example.
What is the specify entity property (i can use "addByteArrayProperty"?).
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use addByteArrayProperty to store the raw bytes of your file.
The file format doesn't matter, you only have to know how to deal with the raw data.

If you have files you could also store the path to the files on your device in your database.

Comment: Thank you!
I decided not to store files in the database, and decided to follow your advice - to keep the path to the files, as in my case, a file number is not known and there may be many, which makes it appropriate not stored in the database